# Difference between ToList()[0] and FirstOrDefault()

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I'm debugging an MVC6 (beta7) application. What I found is that if I execute this test code, the collection has elements (as it should).

```
reservations.ToList()[0].RequestedVehicleType.Photos // Photos.Count == 1
```

With the same data, the original code resulted in an empty collection.

```
reservations.FirstOrDefault().RequestedVehicleType.Photos // Photos.Count == 0
```

What's even more strange is that if I call reservations.ToList() before the 2nd code is executed, the result is good.

```
reservations.ToList();
reservations.FirstOrDefault().RequestedVehicleType.Photos // Photos.Count == 1
```

I understand that MVC6 is currently in beta, and it may have bugs. My question is if this one an expected behavior or a bug?

Comment: I assume, `reservations` is `IQueryable`, not `IEnumerable`?

Comment: This is correct. reservations is IQueryable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Navigation property scenarios are not implemented in beta 7, wait for beta 8 and/or try the daily builds

Comment: Good to know. Interesting that sometimes they work with different data set.

Comment: If this does not work with beta 8, please file a bug!